# “aware” vs “know”

Tags: differences, verbs

What is the difference between *aware* and *know*?

Comment: Wow! A question like this wouldn't survive 24 hours today. Not a single definition, or explanation for the confusion. Please folks, don't take this post as an example on how to write a good question on EL&U. Despite it being potentially interesting, it is a very low quality question nonetheless.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is stated in such a loose way that answers could fill a book. And as Mari-Lou says, it lacks any sign of investigative effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **know** has a **very general meaning of knowledge** and has had this sense for several millenniums.  It can be traced back through Proto Germanic **knoeanan* to the Proto Indo European root **gno-* which also means "to know".
The root itself is common in other Indo European languages: (Gr. γνῶσις gnōsis, knowledge see [*gnostics*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnosticism); or Sanskrit [gyan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyan_%28sanskrit%29), knowledge).

In contrast, to be **aware** (from Old English wær "wary, cautious") is a later addition but initially means **to be cautious**.
You will see remnants of that in *beware* (literally be-*aware* or be cautious) or *wary of*.

If you say

> A known phishing site.

you mean that the characteristic of this site as a phishing site is not ignored.

Whereas if you say,

> Phishing sites are a threat to be aware of.

you give a sense of warning (which of course implies knowledge).

Comment: I'm not sure that this last example is a good one. It would more properly be "A fishing site to be WARY of"

Comment: I agree. It would seem that "be aware of" would more readily be "beware of", which is nearly synonymous with BradC's suggestion.

Comment: @BradC and @msanford, thx for your feedback.  I changed the example in a more neutral way.  Clearly as there is an explicit threat, *wary* can still be substituted to *aware*, but that's the whole point actually.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically:

- "I know that S" where S is a sentence like "It is raining outside right now"
- "I am aware of NP" where NP is a noun phrase like "the fact that it is raining outside right now"

Semantically:

- "I know that it is raining outside right now" - I have direct evidence (I can look out the window) or irrefutable proof (or think I do) that it is raining outside right now.
- "I am aware of the fact that it is raining outside right now" - someone told me, or I am otherwise unsure.

In the example "I know my rights" and "I am aware of my rights", the first means that you could specify (or think that you could specify) what those rights are). The second means that you are somewhat unsure of the details, but you have a general idea of the existence of rights.

Comment: For me, *know* implies knowledge of details or individual pieces, while *am aware of* implies a knowledge only of a whole. Using your example, *knowing* my rights means that I know I have the right to remain silent, the right to be represented by an attorney, etc. Being *aware* of my rights *might* mean the same thing, but implies that I know that I do have rights, but am not sure what those rights are.

Answer (score 1):

'Aware' is an adjective meaning either 'vigilant' or 'informed'. I assume the latter definition relates to your question, as it can be used in place of the verb 'know':

> I know my rights!

Consider the alternative:

> I am aware of my rights.

Both suggest being informed of, or having knowledge of, something. 'Know' has several other definitions, but in this context I would say they can be used interchangeably. The distinction between them is subtle, perhaps related to an intended tone or mood rather than definition.

For example, you often see 'aware' used in a sardonic way to convey scorn or disapproval:

> Bill: Do you know Frank got promoted
>   to Team Leader?
>
> Jim: I'm aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer that I think is very similar, but slightly different from Snubian's (ergo my decision to contribute).

In Snubian's answer, Snubian suggests that on the whole, "aware" and "know" may be used interchangeably and I agree...on the whole.

> However, I want to highlight that we sometimes might choose "aware" over "know" if we are trying to keep ourselves blameless for our ignorance.

Take, for example, [these two (edited) sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126378/the-difference-between-i-was-not-aware-and-i-did-not-know) from the English Language Learners Stack Exchange:

1. I wasn't aware it was his birthday today.
2. I didn't know it was his birthday today.

In the second one, I would say that we are sort of saying that we ourselves are at fault for not having known it was his birthday today.

I suggest this because by its very existence as a verb, to not "know" something means that we ourselves can "do" something about it as we can become aware "through inquiry" ("Know," [Definition 1](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=know&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=dfTtWOSVJev88wfjx7uwDg), Google).

Meanwhile, in the first one, I would say that we are saying (ever so slightly) that someone is at fault for not having given us knowledge (informed us) that it was the birthday boy's birthday on this day ("[Aware](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=aware&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=pfTtWOG2D-v88wfjx7uwDg)," Google).

This someone may be ourselves, but oftentimes, we are talking about someone else who should have been in charge of "making us" aware.

> Thus, while we may not always be to blame for not being aware, we ourselves are almost always to blame for not having known.

But again, I agree with Snubian that the two are interchangeable on the whole.

This slight difference is only from the very nuanced viewpoint of encountering the two in various situations day-to-day.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that "know" implies a whole lot more insight than "aware"; especially in reference to people.  A simple example is "I'm aware of other people in the street, hence I don't walk into them - however, that does not mean I know them".  In this short example you simply cannot say that "know" and "aware" are interchangeable!

Comment: Hello, 364. @Mari-Lou wrote "Wow! A question like this wouldn't survive 24 hours today. Not a single definition, or explanation for the confusion. Please folks, don't take this post as an example on how to write a good question on EL&U.... " And a certain standard for 'answers' is expected also. While unsupported observations / opinions are (if sensible and relevant) welcome, they belong in 'comments'. And yes, we've all wanted to use 'comments' before reaching 50rep. // Aren't you making a false comparison? "I know **that there are** other people in the street." (The question **is** poor.)

Comment: There was an earlier assertion that "know" and "aware" are interchangeable; if you swap them in my sentence, you get "I know that there are other people in the street, hence I don't walk into them - that does not mean I am aware of them!"  First half of sentence can still make sense, but last half becomes nonsense.
You can be aware without (fully) knowing, but you cannot know something and say you are not aware of it.  There is still a degree of knowledge here (implied).